# Python: How to change text of a message widget to a user input

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm making a program which requires a user to enter in a value. I want the value to be displayed via the message widget (or label widget) and updates whenever a new input is enter.

```
def Enter():
    s = v.get()
    print (v.get())

    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, "")

#Code, Code, Code
...

# Area To Enter Text
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(root, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

m = Message(root, text = "Your Input")
m.pack()

# Enter Button
b = Button(root, text="OK", command=Enter)
b.pack()
```

Is there a way for the variable of v to replace the text of Message Widget??

Note:

If I replace `text` with `textvariable`, it updates the text after every character key is pressed, where as I need it to update when the user presses the button.

---

My complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

# All Functions Below
def callback():
    print ("HI")

def Exit():
    os._exit(0)

def Enter():
    s = e.get()
    print (e.get())
    m.configure(text=s)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, "")

def Population():
    root = Tk

    root.mainloop()

def SurvivalRate():
    root = Tk

    root.mainloop()

def BirthRate():
    root = Tk

    root.mainloop()

def NewGen():
    root = Tk

    root.mainloop()

root = Tk()


generation = 0

menubar = Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=callback)
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=Exit)


# Area To Enter Text
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

m = Message(root, text = e)
m.pack()

# Enter Button
b = Button(root, text="OK", command=Enter)
b.pack()

Pop = Button(root, text="Population", command=Population)
Pop.pack()
```

Comment: Take a look at the `command` parameter of a tkinter button.

Comment: Thanks! have to teach a few hours, will look at it later tonight :)

Comment: Ok. But now instead of the `PY_VAR0`, it returns `.56748976`. But I can wait till you get back. Or if anyone else can help, it would be appreciated.

Comment: It is actually a new question. The snippet you posted originally is fine now and runs correctly, the text is fetched correctly.

Comment: ...but by applying what is in the second part of the answer and set your text like: `m = Message(root, text = "Monkey")` fixes it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/fixed.py

Comment: what a strange code - it doesn't work (without IDLE) because it needs `root.mainloop()` in last line. Program should use only one root window (`Tk`) and only one `mainloop()` - subwindows create with `Toplevel()` and subwindows don't need own mainloop.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the info on my code. I haven't really used `Toplevel()`'s before! And what do you mean when you say subwindows?? Do they still create a new window or do the just refresh the window that is already open?

Comment: `subwindows` means dialog windows and popup windows - you still have main window opened but you want to show something in second window. `Tk` creates main window and `Toplevel()` creates second/third window. But if you need one window with different content then you can put widgets in `Frame` and many Frames (with different content) you can put  in window one abow another (so you see only one Frame - top most). Later you can move other frame above anothers and you have different content in window. In one answer on SO is `Page` system which do something like this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add:

```
m.configure(text=s)
```

to your function:

```
def Enter():
    s = v.get()
    print (v.get())
    m.configure(text=s)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, "")
```

---

As a side- note, you do not necessarily need the `StringVar()`. The code below will do exactly the same:

```
def Enter():
    s = e.get()
    m.configure(text=s)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, "")

#Code, Code, Code
...

# Area To Enter Text
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

m = Message(root, text = "Your Input")
m.pack()

# Enter Button
b = Button(root, text="OK", command=Enter)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But befor I enter a character, the label say's `PY_VAR0`. Is there a way to leave it blank?

Comment: @JackBond on the snippet of your code I run, it sais "Your Input", if I embed it in a basic tkinter window. What is your complete code?

Comment: You don't need the `StringVar()` btw. You can directly run `s = e.get()`.